# Servlet getParameter returning null and chrome browser not showing webpage properly

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, servlets

So, I created a java servlet with a  index.html page. I am running tomcat server from eclipse and the chrome browser is not rendering after the `<h3>Adwords API</h3>` where it is being rendered in eclipse tab. (I tried clearing cache but no use).
Here is image in eclipse: https://postimg.org/image/cvyroei2j/
Here is image in chrome: https://postimg.org/image/x08sxijlv/
I've posted only relevant part of the html and javascript code.

Other problem is getParameter() is always returning null. Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container" id="adcontainer">
    <h3 id="heading">Adwords API</h3>
    <form method="post" id="keywordsForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="ads" class="control-label col-xs-3">Enter Keywords:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="ads" name="keywords"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class ="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputURL" class="control-label col-xs-3">Landing Page URL:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputURL" placeholder="rockauto.com">
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class ="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="category" class="control-label col-xs-3">Category:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Auto Parts">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class ="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="location" class="control-label col-xs-3">Location:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Canada">
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return keyData();" id="ads_button">Extract</button>
         </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/updatePage.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
    function keyData(){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { //Assuming you're not on one of the old IEs.
            console.log("Hi!");
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    console.log((xhttp.responseText)); // function to add data to table.
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("POST","/cmstoolweb/AdwordsServlet",false);
            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('keywordsForm'));
            xhttp.send(formData);
          }
          else console.log('not working');
          return false;
}
```

Servlet:

```
    package ca.partsavatar.web;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AdwordsServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/AdwordsServlet")
@MultipartConfig
public class AdwordsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AdwordsServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String adwords = request.getParameter("keywords");
        System.out.println(adwords); //always returnung NULL
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you post request header content in browser network request specific post request?

Comment: My chrome is not showing below Adwords API heading, so I cant click the button to submit the data.

Comment: I've edited the question, to the part I want in html file. This part is not being showed by the chrome but shown in the eclipse tag

Comment: Try removing the form tag and check in browser,also check browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't know why is this happening but the fix was to remove the `id="adheading"` for the div to show up in the chrome browser. And also remove id for the button of the form to make the button show up.